# if/else statement with "contains" argument in file path/type vba

Tags: vba, if-statement, contains

The issue here is that I'm trying to avoid copying files that are ".doc" but it seems to be copying them, and I'm not sure if this is the right way for a contains argument. What I want to do is "If file contains/is a word doc, then ommit and go to next file.

```
Dim FSO as FileSystemObject

Dim MYFSO = New Filesytemobject
Dim MyFile as File 
Dim MyFolder as Folder

Dim copyfolder as Folder
Dim Sourcefolder As string
Dim Destinationfolder as String 

Sourcefolder = "C:\TestA" 
DestinationFolder = "C:\TestB" 

Set myfolder = myfso.getfolder(sourcefolder) 

For each myfile in myfolder.files 
if myfso.getextensionname(myfiles) = ".word" Then 
else myfso.copyfile myfile, destinationfolder 
 end if 
 on error resume next 
next myfile 

end sub
```

Comment: on the line `myfso.getextensionname(myfiles) = ".word" ` should this be `".doc"` ?

Comment: Else should be on it's own line too, then the action to execute on the following.

Comment: I was just using .word as an exmple but I think you're right... I used .pdf and it still copied pdfs from the folder so idk.

Comment: I don't work much with `FSO` but in past when I have I've always referenced the name of the file (as the extension is usually at the end of the file name). Something like `If Right(MyFile.Name, 4) Like *doc* Then`. This looks for the last 4 characters and checks it's like doc (wildcard is used before and after to account for `.doc, .docx, .docm` etc). Might be worth looking into

Comment: You have `For each myfile` (no s) and `myfso.getextensionname(myfiles)` ( with a s) - add Option Explicit to your modules to avoid typos like this

Answer (score 1):

This code will copy the files using the FS object.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CopyFiles()

    Const SourceFolderName  As String = "C:\TestA\"        ' end on backslash
    Const DestFolderName    As String = "C:\TestB\"        ' end on backslash
    
    Dim MyFSO               As Object           ' for late binding
    Dim MyFile              As Object
    Dim MyFolder            As Object
    Dim CopyFolder          As Object
    Dim Sp()                As String
    Dim Ext                 As String
    
    Set MyFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set MyFolder = MyFSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)
    
    For Each MyFile In MyFolder.Files
        Sp = Split(MyFile.Name, ".")
        Ext = Sp(UBound(Sp))                    ' the extension is the last element
        If InStr(1, Ext, "doc", vbTextCompare) <> 1 Then
            MyFSO.CopyFile SourceFolderName & MyFile.Name, DestFolderName & MyFile.Name
        End If
    Next MyFile
End Sub
```

However, my first impulse was to use VBA's own `FileCopy` function which you find code for [here](https://www.educba.com/filecopy-in-vba/).